# coordinator is nil and not navigating to the next screen on button click

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, coordinator-pattern

I have been trying to refactor my source code so that it would conform to the Coordinator Pattern. I have used `UITabBarController` as the parent viewController of my app which contains 4 viewControllers.

I have been following the tutorials on how to implement the Coordinator pattern for iOS apps, and I have created and set up the protocols and classes of the Coordinator. I have a button inside my viewController (child viewController of the TabbarViewController), however, on button click, coordinator is not pushing / navigating to the desired VC, and I see the coordinator is returning `nil` on the debug console while debugging through the `breakpoint`, and I could not figure it out how to resolve this issue.

MainCoordinator.swift:

```
class MainCoordinator: SubCoordinator {
    var subCoordinators = [SubCoordinator]()
    var navigationController: UINavigationController
    
    init(navigationController: UINavigationController) {
        self.navigationController = navigationController
    }
    func start() {
        print("Initialized.. .")
        UIApplication.app().window?.rootViewController = self.navigationController
        let vc = SplashViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
    }
        }
   // testing using a simple Viewcontroller class, its background color is set to red, so if the  
   // navigation works, a blank red VC should appear. but not working so far
    func testView() {
        let vc = ViewController.instantiate()
        vc.coordinator = self
        navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)
       
    }
}
```

SubCoordinator.swift:

```
protocol SubCoordinator {
    var subCoordinators: [SubCoordinator] { get set }
    var navigationController: UINavigationController { get set }
    
    func start()
}
```

`StoryBoarded.swift`:

```
protocol StoryBoarded {
    static func instantiate() -> Self
}
  // I am using storyBoard, and `instantiate()` should instantiate and return the specified VC 
  // from the Storyboard with the specified VC id (?)
extension StoryBoarded where Self: UIViewController {
    static func instantiate() -> Self {
        let id = String(describing: self)
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) as! Self
    }
}
```

FirstViewController.Swift:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, StoryBoarded {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    //MARK: - viewDidLoad()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
   // If uncommented the below line, coordinator is not returning `nil`, but not navigating 
      anyways!
        //coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: UINavigationController())
    }
    @IBAction func onButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {
   // So, basically I would expect the coordinator to navigate to the testView, but not 
      navigating
        coordinator?.testView()
    }
}
```

ViewController.swift:

```
// testView
class ViewController: UIViewController, StoryBoarded {
    var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

and

```
// TabbarController, set as the root VC after the splashVC is completed
class MainViewController: UITabBarController, StoryBoarded {
    var coordinator: MainCoordinator?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let firstVC = UIStoryboard.firstViewController()
        let secondVC = UIStoryboard.secondViewController()
        
        let views: [UIViewController] = [firstVC, secondVC]
        self.setViewControllers(views, animated: false)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }
    
}
```

`start()` is being called, and splashVC  appears and updates rootViewController with `MainViewontroller` on completion, But the navigation is not working at all on button click event.

Any feedback or help would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the StoryBoarded protocol, you should follow the pattern and call instantiate() for initialization. Then, just set the coordinator.

```
class MainViewController: UITabBarController, StoryBoarded {
  var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let firstVC = FirstViewController.instantiate()
    let secondVC = SecondViewController.instantiate()

    firstVC.coordinator = self.coordinator
    secondVC.coordinator = self.coordinator
    
    let views: [UIViewController] = [firstVC, secondVC]
    self.setViewControllers(views, animated: false)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is needed if you follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7HgbcTqxoN4&t=777s. The same things are followed by @dev. I am seeing a similar problem where the coordinator is nil. Can you please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got this working.

refer : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tb3PlVFq3YY, Time : 6.59

For some reason, I could not get my project working as the coordinator was nil and I could see a black screen. On looking at other examples I got it working by moving the window set up inside the **SceneDelegate.swift** under the willConnectTo method. I had to also add this extra line to make things work **window?.windowScene = windowScene**

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else {
            return
        }
        
    
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
        
        let navController = UINavigationController()
        coordinator = MainCoordinator(navigationController: navController)
        coordinator?.start()
        
        window?.rootViewController = navController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

refer
[image]
[image]